# Points in rectangular coordinate system - specifying coordinates as function values

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to locate the vertices of a rectangle and to color the rectangular region.  I specify the y-coordinate as a function value, like `\sqrt{3}/2` or `\sin(60)`.  I am getting an error.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A) at (-1,{-\sqrt{3}/2});
\coordinate (B) at (-1,{\sin(60)});
\coordinate (C) at (2,{\sin(60));
\coordinate (D) at (2,{-\sqrt{3}/2});

\path[fill=yellow] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;

\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label={[fill=white]below left:$A$}] at (A) {};
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label={[fill=white]above left:$B$}] at (B) {};
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label={[fill=white]above right:$C$}] at (C) {};
\node[outer sep=0pt,circle, fill,inner sep=1.5pt,label={[fill=white]below right:$D$}] at (D) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You can use polar coordinates, if you don't know. `(angle:radius)`

Comment: Just typping problems: `(-1,{-sqrt(3)/2});` and `(2,{sin(60)});`

Comment: @Ignasi  I am missing a right brace, or I am misplacing a right parenthesis.  Ooops!

Comment: @Sigur  With the proper order of braces and parentheses, I can also specify the angle and radius of a point, specified in polar coordinates, as functions.  Is that correct?

Comment: Don't forget to supres backslashes in front of `calc` functions

Comment: @Ignasi  Yes, I had `\sqrt{3}` and not `sqrt{3}`.  Why is that?  I thought `TikZ` was based on `LaTeX'.

Comment: @Sigur  I see that I get an error with `\coordinate (A) at (-1,{-sqrt{3}/2});` but not with `\coordinate (A) at (-1,{-sqrt(3)/2});`.  Why can't I use braces about `3`?

Comment: This is not `LaTeX`, it is `TikZ`! ;-)

Comment: @user143462 `\sqrt` is a macro to typeset (square)roots in math-mode. `sqrt` (in this context) is a PGFmath function that evaluates to the squareroot of its parameter. All PGFmath functions use `(`, `,` and `)` to delimit their parameters. For one-parameter functions you can also do `(-1, sqrt 3/2)` and `(2, sin 60)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although `TikZ`/`pgf` is used in `LaTeX`, its syntax is particular, as is the syntax of `pgf`'s math engine.

In this particular case, funtions like `sqrt` or `sin` doesn't start command name with `\` (backslash). And compound arguments which need parenthesis must be surrounded by `{...}`. The correct code for `coordinates` definition should be:

```
\coordinate (A) at (-1,{-sqrt(3)/2}); 
\coordinate (B) at (-1,{sin(60)});
\coordinate (C) at (2,{sin(60)});
\coordinate (D) at (2,{-sqrt(3)/2});
```